# How can I integrate my Magento2 project with firebase to send push notifications to user?

Tags: magento2.3, firebase, push-notifications

I want to send push notification using firebase to all customers in Magento2.

Comment: When do you want to send this notifications? Its important to know :)

Comment: Let's say the app is running in background I want to push notification

Comment: Whenever you want or for example when order is complete, or when customer is logged in? Its different to develop a module to send notification whenever you want or when an action is triggered.

Comment: Let's say for customer Login

Comment: I posted an answer, maybe it will help you. Just add your code and test it! If it helps you, don't forget to accept the answer! :)

Comment: thanks for your quick response.Actually I am a beginner can you please write some demo firebase code in your answer?

Comment: You can learn how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620137/firebase-php-send-notification-to-everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` controller, and send the push notification.
For example, this module will execute an action after customer is logged in.

Folder structure:

```
app
|__ code
    |_Vendor
      |__ Module
         |__ etc
            |_ di.xml
            |_ module.xml
         |__ Plugin
            |_ AfterLoginPost.php
         |_ composer.json
         |_ registration.php
```

Files:

> registration.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

> composer.json

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "N/A",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "*",
    "magento/module-customer": "103.0.*"
  },
  "license": [
    "Proprietary"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="AfterLoginPost"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AfterLoginPost"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Plugin/AfterLoginPost.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class AfterLoginPost
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private Session $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param LoginPost $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        LoginPost $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            // TODO: Connect to Firebase and send push notification here.
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Just, change whatever you need, and add your code to connect with firebase in the plugin.

Execute `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and test it.